# error in using "cross_validate_fn" function from "cvms" package and "ub" function from "ebmc" package

Tags: r

I have been trying to cross-validate an under-bagging model using 5*5-fold cross-validation. However, I got an error:

> "Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "--- cross_validate_fn(): Error
> in `purrr::map()`: ℹ In index: 1. Caused by error in `if (xi > xj) ...`: ! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Here is an example using the "participant.scores" data from the "cvms" package:

```r
# load packages  
library(groupdata2)
library(dplyr)
library(cvms)
library(ebmc)
library(stats)

# read the data  
df <- participant.scores
table(df$diagnosis)
df$diagnosis <- ifelse(df$diagnosis==0,1,0) #to change the imbalance for label "1"
table(df$diagnosis)
```

```r
# Create initial groups  
df_1 <- fold(
  data = df,
  k = 5,
  method = "n_dist",
  id_col = "participant",
  handle_existing_fold_cols = "remove"
)
df_1 <- dplyr::ungroup(df_1)

# collapse  
df_1$diagnosis <- as.factor(df_1$diagnosis)

df_coll <- collapse_groups(
  data = df_1,
  n = 3,
  group_cols = ".folds",
  cat_cols = "diagnosis",
  id_cols = "participant",
  balance_size = TRUE,
  num_new_group_cols = 5,
  auto_tune = TRUE
)

formula <- "diagnosis~score"

# Create model function  

UB_model_fn <- function(train_data, formula,hyperparameters) {
  require(ebmc)
  ebmc::ub(formula = formula,data = train_data,ir = 1,size = 100,
           rf.ntree = 1000,
           alg= "rf")
}

# Create predict function  
UB_predict_fn <- function(test_data, model,formula,hyperparameters,train_data) {
  predictions <- stats::predict(
    object = model,
    newdata = test_data,
    allow.new.levels = TRUE,
    probability = TRUE
  )
}
```

```r
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(10)

# Cross validate  
cv_TD <- cross_validate_fn(
  df_coll,
  formulas = formula,
  type = "binomial",
  model_fn = UB_model_fn,
  predict_fn = UB_predict_fn,
  hyperparameters = NULL,
  fold_cols = names(df_coll[,7:11]),
  positive = 2,
  metrics = "all",
  #rm_nc = FALSE,
  parallel = TRUE,
  verbose = TRUE
)
```

> "Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "--- cross_validate_fn(): Error
> in `purrr::map()`: ℹ In index: 1. Caused by error in `if (xi > xj) ...`: ! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

I checked the model without cross-validation as:

```r
mod <- ub(diagnosis~score,data = df_coll, ir = 1,size = 100, rf.ntree = 1000, alg= "rf")
```

I got the following error:

> Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE
> needed   In addition: Warning messages:   1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x):
> cannot xtfrm data frames   2: In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not
> meaningful for factors

Following this, I checked the "ub" function specifications & I realized that it requires a data frame as input. I changed the "df_coll" data to a data frame and redone the model without cross-validation. No error appeared. However, when I do this for the repeated cross-validation functions, the error still appears. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the model function requires a raw data frame instead of a tibble, you can add `as.data.frame()` within the model function as such:

```r
UB_model_fn <- function(train_data, formula,hyperparameters) {
  require(ebmc)
  ebmc::ub(
    formula = formula,
    data = as.data.frame(train_data),
    ir = 1,
    size = 100,
    rf.ntree = 1000,
    alg= "rf"
  )
}
```

This seems to run.

In the future, feel free to post links to cvms problems on the [cvms github page](https://github.com/LudvigOlsen/cvms), so I am notified and can help you out :-)